# How can I get libatlas-base-dev version?

Tags: linux

I have installed libatlas-base-dev on my Ubuntu Trusty Tahr:

```
sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev
```

Which command can I use to get the version of the library installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try    `dpkg -l | grep libatlas-base-dev` or `dpkg -l | grep libatlas`

Comment: dpkg -l | grep "libatlas-base-dev" works fine :) Thanks a lot for answer :)